# i can burn .iso image but i can't burn new data dvd

Tags: burning

```
BraseroLibburn SCSI error condition on command 2Ah WRITE(10): [3 0C 00] Write error
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_get_session_output_size
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_set_current_action
BraseroLibburn Libburn reported an error SCSI error on write(32,16): [3 0C 00] Write error
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_error
BraseroLibburn finished with an error
BraseroLibburn asked to stop because of an error
    error       = 1
    message = "SCSI error on write(32,16): [3 0C 00] Write error"
BraseroLibisofs stopping
BraseroLibisofs Getting out thread
BraseroLibisofs disconnecting BraseroLibisofs from BraseroChecksumImage
BraseroChecksumImage stopping
BraseroChecksumImage disconnecting BraseroChecksumImage from BraseroLibburn
BraseroChecksumImage closing connection for BraseroChecksumImage
BraseroLibburn stopping
BraseroLibburn closing connection for BraseroLibburn
Session error : SCSI error on write(32,16): [3 0C 00] Write error (brasero_burn_record brasero-burn.c:2856)
```

Comment: Have you tried it with any other burning software (e.g. k3b) or on a different OS (e.g. Windows)?

Answer (score 0):

Test this:

Open a terminal,

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

Run it:

```
sudo -i
apt-get update
apt-get install --reinstall brasero brasero-cdrkit brasero-common cdrdao cdparanoia cue2toc dvdauthor dvd+rw-tools genisoimage wodim
```

Comment: not working, maybe the answer is in synaptic package manager

Answer (score 0):

The error message stems from the DVD drive and means that
it failed to write the third chunk of 32 KB of data.
This is not a software problem. Try other media or a
different drive.

Comment: tried k3b but the same, after brasero reinstallation is the same

Comment: I hate to deliver bad news about hardware.
But SCSI error key 3 indicates "Medium error".
Since the diagnosis stems from the drive, it
might also be due to a bad drive.